# Cannot Import TensorFlow on Windows 7 Professional

Tags: tensorflow

I've tried using different versions of TensorFlow, I've tried setting up different paths but no matter what I do I get the following error.
I'm using Spyder v3.2.8, Python v3.6.6, and TensorFlow v1.11.0 on Windows 7 Professional.

import keras
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "<ipython-input-1-88d96843a926>", line 1, in <module>
import keras

File "C:\Users\dchisholm\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3.3.7\envs\Python35\Lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from . import utils

File "C:\Users\dchisholm\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3.3.7\envs\Python35\Lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
from . import conv_utils

File "C:\Users\dchisholm\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3.3.7\envs\Python35\Lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
from .. import backend as K

File "C:\Users\dchisholm\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3.3.7\envs\Python35\Lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
from .tensorflow_backend import *

File "C:\Users\dchisholm\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3.3.7\envs\Python35\Lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in <module>
import tensorflow as tf

File "C:\Users\dchisholm\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3.3.7\envs\Python35\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import

File "C:\Users\dchisholm\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3.3.7\envs\Python35\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow

File "C:\Users\dchisholm\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3.3.7\envs\Python35\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
raise ImportError(msg)

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\dchisholm\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3.3.7\envs\Python35\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
File "C:\Users\dchisholm\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3.3.7\envs\Python35\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
File "C:\Users\dchisholm\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3.3.7\envs\Python35\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
File "C:\Users\dchisholm\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3.3.7\envs\Python35\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
File "C:\Users\dchisholm\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3.3.7\envs\Python35\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: Are you using Anaconda ? A _conda_ environment with all the dependencies will help you  avoid such teething problems.

Comment: Yes everything I've installed so far has been through Anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what the problem was. The python version needed to be 3.5.x and all of the TensorFlow packages needed to be 1.8.0. Other version variations I tried resulted in import failures.

Using these in conjunction, keras modules were able to be imported and I was able to set up an ANN without issue.